# Laptop Keyboard Issue with Few Keys [Caps, A, Q, Z, 1 and Esc]

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, hardware

In My Laptop keyboard's few keys are not working [Caps, A, Z, Q, 1 and Esc], also sometime it working fine on startup with few seconds.

After that again its going to disable.

What's wrong with this ?

Hardware/ Software Issue ?

I Face this issue on after installing ubuntu !

Comment: You might have selected a wrong keymap

Comment: Yep, u are write man. At Default key map as 105 and i change it into 101, now working fine. Thank you !

Comment: I have added it as an answer. Please upvote it and mark it as selected so that it does not appear in unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can possibly be due to selecting a wrong keymap ( e.g. Selecting Dvorak Style for a qwerty keyboard). Change the keymap for the keyboard in order to correct the error.